# Integer root of an equation

Tags: roots

I saw this question somewhere, have a doubt whether it's correct.

Suppose $a_1, a_2 \cdots a_{2n}$ are distinct integers.
The equation $(x-a_1)(x-a_2)...(x-a_{2n})-(-1)^n(n!)^2$=0

has an integer solution

$r=(a_1+a_2...+a_{2n})/2^n$.

Comment: How do we know that $2^{n}|(a_1 + a_2 ... + a_{2n})$?

Comment: If $a_1 = 1$, and $a_2 = 2$, then $r$ is not an integer, nor a solution to the equation.

Comment: setai.. some junour asked me.. Indrayudh Roy

Answer (score 1):

I tried using $a(i)=i$ for many values of $n$. I have not been able to find any case where this happens.

Please, take into account that I did not perform millions of runs.

Using the case given by fuglede, the roots are complex.